# When is uniform space normal

Tags: general-topology

We know that metric spaces are normal. We also know that a uniform space is Hausdorff if the intersection of all entourages is the diagonal, in which case it is even regular.

However, is there a *necessary and sufficient* criterion to ensure that a uniform space is normal (A sufficient condition would be, for example, the space is metrizable)? I have read Bourbaki, *General Topology* as well as Willard, *General topology*, but I was not able to find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question, I think. You might be aware that uniform spacs also have a cover reformulation, and normality does have a cover equivalent (point finite covers are shrinkable). This might be the way to go, I'm not sure. I at least never heard of such a charcterisation, but then again,  I'm no expert on uniform spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it~ @HennoBrandsma